# What happens when you die while traveling internationally?

Tags: international-travel, legal

The possibility of dying while travelling always existed. One could get into a car accident, victim of crime, etc, so the question is:

**What happens when you die?**

Specifically, are there international treaties that establish a procedure to follow when a foreigner dies in a certain country? Now, I know that *International* treaties are rarely signed by all nations, so there will be exceptions but if there are common agreements and procedures, those are the ones I would like to know.

If there are any: **What do these treaties say?** Do they include following a will legally written in another country.

Are procedures depending on the country of death, citizenship, residence or combination of these? If there are no treaties covering death of a foreigner, then it is possible we have to ask what happens when an Afghan dies in Albania to a Zambian in Zimbabwe!

Comment: The question is very broad and multifacetted, not sure it's a good fit for this site. Why would you think or hope there are common procedures or that bodies would systematically be repatriated (and to which “home” country)?

Comment: https://www.nfda.org/resources/operations-management/shipping-remains/death-abroad has some information that may be useful in an answer.

Comment: @Relaxed - Thanks, simplified and you are right, *hope* was a poor choice of wording. Just want to know what common agreements exist, if any, before we go on to very specific versions between all country-pairs. The answer can be that it depends on the pair of countries and I'm fine with that too, just because there is no one answer doesn't mean the question is broad because the asker is unlikely to know.

Comment: Fair enough, I ended up writing an answer.

Comment: "asking for a friend"

Comment: You stop caring about what happens when you die.

Comment: Would the title be better phrased as ‘… **if** …’ rather than ‘…when…’?  After all, many of us won't die while travelling abroad.

Comment: @mustaccio Exactly: Why on earth would you care?

Comment: For all the reasons people write a will :)

Comment: Would it make sense to include **and carry** instructions about what you desire to happen if you die? "If I die when traveling, please have me cremated and contact my widow for reimbursement and for repatriation of my ashes."

Comment: @Itai, well, a will is used to distribute one's wealth, a very useful act to further the (monetary) wellbeing of people one cared about when still alive. - But I, for instance, don't care at all what will happen to my corpse, as it will be of little value to anyone. It's just a piece of meat, that you aren't even allowed to eat or make other use of. - Your reasoning is thus flawed: The reasons to care about one's corpse are not the same as the ones to write a will.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica it might affect the mourning of the people one cares about

Comment: Anyone of you guys have ever thought of signing for organ donation? There are other things you can do with meat and in some cultures, indeed, the corpse is eaten during the funeral ceremony. Donation instructions are registered somewhere but it might not be known to the foreign country you die in.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, you would just be buried locally according to the local procedures. In particular, if some burial practices are forbidden or there is a short delay to dispose of the remains, these rules still apply. Being a foreign national would not necessarily prevent the local authorities from proceeding with a burial.

If the family wants the remains to be buried differently or elsewhere, they have to bear the costs and face different hurdles (to get the permission on both ends, etc.) It's possible to get some assistance from your country's consulates abroad, from companies specializing in this (some funeral homes advertise these services) or to get an insurance covering the costs (“repatriation of remains“).

Article 37 of the Vienna Convention on Consular Relations does provide that when a state learns of the death of a foreign national, they should inform their consulate. This convention has been ratified by nearly all countries in the world and reflects older international customs so this rule would be observed very broadly.

Comment: The insurance term for this coverage, by the way, is "repatriation of remains".  At least in the USA, it is frequently included in travel insurance policies.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks, I added that to the answer.

Comment: Addition: I believe ( = should really check sources ) that if you die in a plane crash or on a ship there might be special rules.